# keytool : Certificate import gives error message - Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, keytool

**My goal is to generate a certificate, export it in a file and import in JDK keystore.**

In first step I have generated a self signed certificate using following command, providing password as 'password' for keystore and key:

```
keytool   -genkeypair  -keystore .keystore  -alias uasera  -keyalg RSA
```

In second step I exported the certificate using similar password and following command:

```
keytool  -exportcert  -keystore  .keystore  -alias usera  -file usera.crt
```

**NOW!**

I am trying to import this certificate in cacerts in JDK using similar password and following command but getting exception.

```
keytool -importcert -file usera.crt -keypass password  -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

**ERROR**

K:\java\certificates>keytool -importcert -file usera.crt -keypass password  -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Comment: `-keypass` specifies the password for the alias of a single key in the keystore.  If you are specifying the password to the keystore file itself, you want to use `-storepass`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I have got this sorted out. I was using my password that is 'password' to update cacerts keystore in JDK while **default password for cacerts keystore is 'changeit'**

Comment: Thanks I was just about to post my related question when i stumbled upon this. With me the inverse was happening, I was using 'changeit' when i should have been using 'password'

Comment: As an added note, if you're trying to use the `cacerts` keystore, you should use the `-cacerts` argument instead of `-keystore <path>` to handle it.

Comment: I never knew the default password is `changeit`

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you're able to build your app from a PC, but you don't recall the password, here's what you can do to retrieve the password:

**Method 1:**

In your build.gradle, add `println MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD` as below:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            println MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
```

After that, run `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

Method 2:

Run `keytool -list -v -keystore your <.keystore file path`> e.g. keytool -list -v -keystore ./app/my-app-key.keystore.

It will ask for you to Enter keystore password: Just press enter key here. and you will be able to find mapped to Alias name:

Then, run `grep -rn "<your alias name>"` . in your terminal and you will be able to see your signing.json file as below:

```
./app/build/intermediates/signing_config/release/out/signing-config.json
```

The file will have your password in json format with key `"mKeyPassword":" < your password > "`