# When building release apk using android studio, i get a error "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, keystore, android-keystore

It's so strange, I have created a keystore using android studio before.
And my studio is canary channel(1.4), I always keep studio updated. 
Last day I get that error, I even downgraded my studio to  the stable channel(1.3). 
**But when I build using gradle in command line**, everything is fine.
I am sure my password is right.

Full error is :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDevRelease'.
```

> Failed to read key ** from store "D:\work\app_proj\Android\jxj\trunk\JXJ\app\szyx.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Comment: Have you given any special characters in your password?

Comment: It's just like stack0verfl0w@2015 . Studio can build before, suddenly it's broken. Event i uninstall it and do a clean install. I have no idea...

Comment: According to me , your **KeyStore** file has some error within it.

Comment: Default password for keystore is changeit.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965453/keytool-certificate-import-gives-erro-message-keystore-was-tampered-with-or

Comment: @vvv Would you happen to be using any google play services libraries? Which ones and how?

Comment: @Jonathan727 I have not use any google play services libraries. The newest version studio( 1.4 )  still get same error

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it! (for me at least)

I found the issue is somehow related to the gradle plugin.

When I changed

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
}
```

in my project's *build.gradle*, it fixed the problem.

Just like the OP, I was able to sign builds created using the IDE's *play* button, but just not the ones that I created through the *Generate signed APK...* menu option.

After searching, I found this [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187532).

Comment: Definitely it is a gradle plugin bug,  and downgrade is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Default Password for keystore is changeit and you can also refer the below results.

[keytool : Certificate import gives error message - Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965453/keytool-certificate-import-gives-erro-message-keystore-was-tampered-with-or)

[keytool error Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect)

[Keytool Signing Problem: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262773/keytool-signing-problem-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect)

Comment: It's release key, not debug key . I use "keytool -list -keystore mykeyh",  input password, and it can list information

Answer (score -2):

Just as the message suggest, it should be either your password incorrect, or you keystore file is has data error.

Comment: It is a file, it can be corrupted, have you saved a backup?

Comment: I hava a backup,but gradle can work using just same file.

Comment: Actually you can just try with creating a new keystore, if it works then you would know the error is on your keystore file or password but nothing else.

Comment: I mean have you got a backup of the keystore file, if you do, just restore the backup.

Comment: Yes, I have a backup,but still get same error. If I create a new release key, it can work.

Comment: Then you can be sure that it is your keystore-password pair not matching. Sorry to ask something like this, but maybe you should check your capslock.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I event input my password in texteditor, and then copy to studio input dialog. And if I put same password in command terminal using gradle, everything is fine...

Comment: If it is the case, I think you should try reinstall a clean Android Studio, maybe something weird going on after you access the version with canary channel. Android's new changes are indeed quite broken, personally I would avoid try to avoid it until it is more stable. You should edit your original post and mention about the the success in command line but not Android Studio, it is a very important piece of information.

Comment: Thanks, last day I uninstall it ,but maybe still have some profiles that not be deleted. I will search how to delete Android Studio completely ^_^

Comment: I have the same issue with v1.4 and it's building fine with gradle from the command line. So it's definitely an issue introduced by an Android Studio update and this answer is plain wrong.

Comment: It's *not* the keystore - I know because I keep my keystore in a git repo and git is not reporting a change in the file. Whatever code is generating the message, is wrong. Google needs to fix.