# Error:Failed to read key changeit from store Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262773/keytool-signing-problem-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965453/keytool-certificate-import-gives-erro-message-keystore-was-tampered-with-or) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453249/apk-signing-error-failed-to-read-key-from-keystore?rq=1) but my problem doesnt solve. Am not able to understand what am doing wrong. 
here is my signing Configs

```
  signingConfigs {

    config {
        keyAlias 'changeit'
        keyPassword 'changeit'
        storeFile file('C:/Users/abc/.android/debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'changeit'
    }
}
```

And this is the error it is showing when am trying to run the application `Error:Failed to read key changeit from store "C:\Users\abc\.android\debug.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

cant figure out what to do.. thanks for the help in advance.

Edit - Adding screenshot of the error.[image]

Comment: Can you access the keystore via command line with the alias and password listed?

Comment: yes i can access and it shows SHA1 key and some other things there, but when i run my application it gives this error.

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar did you find a solution?

Comment: @JCarlos yeah, i start the process from starting and make a new key and clicked the checkbox to be remember in future as well :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sign your for release app, generate a new key and sign it with that: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: So you generated a new keystore, alias,    and password, then after entering that in your release configuration you got the same error?